# Import cytoscape.js as ESM module

Tags: angular, cytoscape.js

I'm using [cytoscape.js](https://js.cytoscape.org/) in an Angular 10 application. The documentation of cytoscape.js says

> To use Cytoscape.js in an ESM environment with npm (e.g. Webpack or
> Node.js with the ESM package): `import cytoscape from 'cytoscape';`

I import it like `import cytoscape from 'cytoscape';` in my typescript file.

But I see warnings

> CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.

So I go to `node_modules\cytoscape\dist` folder. I see that there are many importable files.

[image]

I put `console.log` to each one of them. Then I see that I'm using `cytoscape.cjs.js` which means I'm using commonjs file.

I might copy `cytoscape.esm.min.js` and import it manually but is there a better way?
It would be better to track all my dependencies from `package.json`

Answer (score 1):

I googled for this a while ago and found out there is no support for typescript yet. So I just did the same import as you did and added cytoscape to angular.json: projects.yourprojectname.architect.build.options.allowedCommonJSDependencies like this:

```
 "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "cytoscape",
              "cytoscape-popper",
              "lodash",
              "lodash/cloneDeep"
            ]
```

Comment: Actually, there is typescript support but it is not official I guess. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/cytoscape 
Also, cytoscape.js works like this `var cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy') // container to render in
});`
So it gathers all its functionality in one single object, I think even if we import it as an ESM module, it doesn't improve performance much. It would improve the performance if cytoscape.js was more modular so that we could just import or not import multiple things. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Typescript support would help to understand the result of calls, and all secundary objects (cytoscape collections, nodes etc). I'm going to have a look at the typedefs.

Comment: typescript will make things definitely more understandable

Comment: Hmm, when I install this, my `import cytoscape from 'cytoscape';` breaks.

Comment: You may have to use 'cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.esm.js'.  The 'module' field can't be updated in the project's package.json in v3, as it would break Webpack.  See https://js.cytoscape.org/#getting-started/including-cytoscape.js